# Archaic verb conjugation: knowest vs know'st

Tags: archaicisms, conjugation

When using the archaic 2sg-present conjugation for English verbs, when would you use the longer form (eg `knowest`) and when would you use the shorter form (`know'st')?

Is it like contemporary English contractions, generally indicating a less formal register?

Comment: At the time this conjugation was common, spelling was not well standardized. Writers often conveyed variations of pronunciation with variations of spelling.

Comment: Or if you read this in a poem or play, they may have abbreviated to keep the meter.

Comment: @ThePhoton: Yes, definitely to keep the meter. And as the OP suggests, the other purpose would be to reflect the informal pronunciation - although this particular example somewhat belies that, as it would be strange to pronounce *know'st* as strictly monosyllabic (rhyming with "toast")